# How can I show search result separate page using react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am a fresher MERN stack developer. I want that when a user will search a keyword in the search input, the search result will **show** on a **specific page**. Could you help me by giving me any idea or an **example of code** for implementing it?

Comment: 2 questions -
you want to use the same url as the current one for search page or different one?
you want to change the page on any action like "enter" or just as user is typing?

Comment: I want to change the page and there I want to show user search result. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const App = () =>{
   const history = useHistory();

   // navigate to your page and pass searched value as a router state.
   history.push({ pathname: '/page', state: { searchKeyword: 'searchedValue' } 
   })
}
```

// use it like this in a /page

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
const Page = () =>{
  const location = useLocation();
  location?.state?.searchKeyword // you can access the search string by this. and get result 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham Jasani. Now I am trying to implement it then I will give you feedback soon for this. Thank you again.